# I want to export all products from backend

Tags: magento-1.9

**[image: strong text]**

I want to add export option in MANAGE PRODUCT as same as shown in above image for ORDERS

Answer (score 1):

By default you can't export products from the Manage Products view, you could look into purchasing an extension to customise this but would be best to use Magento's export functionality.

If you navigate to `System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Profiles` you can create a new profile to export all products and fields or pick and choose the fields you want to export.

Here is a video tutorial which goes over exporting products in Magento - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qjz…